# Oracle SQL Developer - How to add constraints to er diagram

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, erd

I need to create an ER diagram using oracle SQL developer, I have created it, but I am struggling to add the constraints, does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

I am developing a hospital data model. Thanks

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you looking for [PK/FK](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/01/drawing-foreign-keys-relationships-in-sql-developer-data-modeler/) or any type?  or [auto generate](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/how-to-generate-an-erd-for-selected-tables-in-sql-developer/) based on existing structures?

Comment: I'm new to SQL and developing models, but I have set my pk, and I'm pretty sure they're correct, I'm a bit confused with fk and also any other kind of constraints I can add.

Comment: Primary key/Foreign Key; in other words what value (or values) uniquely defines a record in a table for PK and when linking that value to another table the PK becomes a FK to the secondary table.  So think of a Invoice with lines on it.  Invoice # ties to Invoice Detail using Invoice # but Invoice Detail also has a Line # to make it unique in that table.  So while Invoice# and LIne# are PK in Invoice Detail, Invoice # is PK in Invoice Table it's also a FK in Invoice Detail.

Comment: Thank you for that, that makes it clearer! I have added an image of my diagram, does this seem right to you?

Comment: So is a patient record a "visit' thus you would be duplicating patient name dob gender each time or do you have patients independent of the visits?  To me a patient could have multiple visits to a dr with different complaints/ailments each time and it could be more than 1 per visit.  So there should be a table between patient visits and complaints so if multiple exists it's handled.    For each Table/Entity you need to ask how does this relate to the other entities.  If it could ever be a Many-to-Many then you need an associative table.  I'm not sure how you came up with the table structure./

Comment: When a patient is admitted for treatment they are assigned to one ward only, however they may receive treatment from more than one doctor depending on the number and types of complaints they have. The hospital also keeps records of GPs so that they can be sent information regarding their patients treatment, the GP is different to the hospital doctors. Is my diagram completely wrong?

Comment: I would keep patient independant of the "admittance" since a patient could be admitted multiple times over different dates.  The "GP" would be tied directly to the patient and thus multiple patients could have the same GP and you onjly have to maintain teh contact info once.  Each admittance would be tied to a ward.  Each admittance would be tied to one or Many complaints as each complaint may require a different doctor. in that complaint/admittance table I would list the dr repsonsible for each complaint. but only if that makes sense to the business.

Comment: It's not all wrong by any means; but there are areas where I would question the setup given my limited knowledge of the hospital and medical fields.  Are you actually designing the database or just creating the ERD off an existing database?

Comment: I'm making it based on the information given on my task sheet, I've attached a copy of it now. I'm not sure how to chat you but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Common mistakes are to clone the user forms; don't do that think about what entities exist and how they relate.  You're duplicating tables/data unnecessairly. I'm working on an outline now.

Answer (score 1):

So reconsider your entities  Think of it in terms of What "physical objects do you have and what can those objects do"

Start off by identifying them all and then combining like ones.

For example staff, dr, GP and patient are all "People" and share like information just There are just different "Types" of people so combine them!

Each ward has staff on it so you have People, Ward, and WardStaff
Each person could have address information.
A Person can be admitted to a ward
A persons who has been admitted can be treated by multiple drs and have multiple ailments

Remember if you have to update information in more than one place to keep it accurate it needs to be consolidated.

Consider Cardinality between the entities: Does a ward HAVE to have nurses assigned?  is a Nurce always on a ward?  Can a ward have zero, one or many nurses?
Can a patient have zero one or many ailments? 
Can a dr have zero one or many patients?
Are dr's limited to wards?
Do Dr's have specialties too? (can they have more than one?)

## Here's the entities I see after that read:

- Ward
- WardType
- WardStaff
- Admittance
- Person
- PersonType
- Address
- PatentAdmittanceAilments
- AilmentType
- TreatmentType

And then here's how I see them relate.  Re-read the 4 pages and see if this looks right. ask what's wrong and ask what's missing.  and is there too much?

## Wards

- WardID       (int) PK
- Name     (varchar(10))
- WardTypeID   (int)

## WardStaff

- WardID       (int)       PK
- StaffID      (Varchar(6))    PK  (Unique Constraint) as a nurse can only work in 1 ward
- LeadEffective    Date        Shows when the nurse became lead of ward
- LeadNurseID  (varchar(6))    FK to PersonID

## Admittance

- AdmittanceID    (int)        PK
- PatientID       (VARCHAR(6))
- WardID       (Int)       FK to Ward
- AdmittanceDate   (date)
- DischargeDate    (date)

## Person

- PersonID     (varchar(6))  PK
- PersonTypeID     (Integer)
- Name         (varchar(30))
- DOB Date (Date)
- GPID     (6,0)
- AddressID    (int)   FK to Address

## Address

- AddressID        (Int) PK
- Address#         (varchar(10))
- BuildingName     (varchar(30))
- Unit#            (varchar(10))
- City         (Varchar(50))
- Street           (varchar(50))
- State            (varchar(02))
- Country          (varchar(10))
- ZipCode          (varchar(10))

## PatientAdmittanceAilments

- AdmittanceID     (Int) PK_1of3
- DrID     (varchar(06))  FK to Person
- AilmentID    (int)          FK to Ailment PK2of3     A trigger needs ot be created to
- ensure a compliantID
- AilmentAdditional(varchar(40))                   doesn't overlap the DTS/DTE
- TreatmentID  (int)  FK to Treatment
- TreatmentAdditional(varchar(40))
- DTS          (Date)      PK3of3
- DTE      (Date)

## PersonType

- PersonTypeID     (Int)  PK
- Description      (Varchar(30)) (Examples: Staff, Patient, Dr, GP)

## WardType

- WardTypeID       (int) PK
- Description  (varchar(20)) (Examples: Orthopaedic, geriatric...)

## AilmentType

- AilmentTypeID    (int) PK
- Description  (varchar(40))

## Treatments

- TreatmentTypeID  (int) PK
- Description  (varchar(40))

Comment: Thank you so much for going through this! I'm just going through it now

Comment: Can I just ask how do I highlight constraints for this?

Comment: The lines between the documents are the PK/FK constraints... the broken line vs solid lines define optional vs mandatiory relationships and the crows feet denote 1 to many.  So they are "hilighted" in that aspect.. I'm not sure what you mean beyond that.